# Set Default Value in dropdown list in UI when the dropdown is an ngModel

Tags: angular, angular-forms

The problem I'm facing is this. So I have 3 dropdowns in a form. I need them all to be in the ngModel and display in the console. The first two dropdowns have indicators on the left side of the dropdown list when ANY value of the list is selected. These two dropdowns are using the ngModel in their tag. The 3rd one doesnt need this functionality but without ngModel it wont go up in the console. Right now I have this, and it is selecting all the select tags to have this validator:

```
`select.ng-dirty[required], select.ng-dirty.required 
{
  border-left: 5px solid #42A948; /* green */
}

select.ng-pristine:not(form) 
{
  border-left: 5px solid #a94442; /* red */
}`
```

I realize I can just take the ngModel off of the third dropdown but here is the kicker. I need to have the dropdown show a default value when the page loads and if I dont have ngModel it will do that but i need it for the console.